# How to clean icon home file from my desktop ? ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04, gnome

How to clean my desktop?

[image: my desktop]

I tried to install pspp for my statistic exam. After rebooting, my desktop has many files like that. How to fix that? I have used Tweaks but cannot do it.

Comment: What do you mean *"How to clean my desktop?"* You want to have no icons on the desktop? If so, open Extensions and disable the *Desktop Icons* extension near the bottom of the list.

Comment: This happened because in some undeliberated moment, you deleted the "Desktop" folder in your home directory. That is where normally the files living on the desktop reside. If you delete it, the entire home folder becomes your desktop.